# json_decode not working from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm sending an array of objects to php from javascript with ajax (fyi - I have dataType:"json" in the ajax code)

My array toSource() in JS displays

```
[{f:135, p:0}, {f:136, p:1}, {f:134, p:2}]
```

JSON.stringify on my js array shows

```
[{"f":135,"p":0},{"f":136,"p":1},{"f":134,"p":2}]
```

After stripslashes, php spits out

```
[{"f":135,"p":0},{"f":136,"p":1},{"f":134,"p":2}]
```

json_decode on this spits out

```
Array
```

Should I not get an array of some sort after the last step? What am I coding incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please give us some code to debug here...

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) outputs the array structure, [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) doesn't.

Comment: Thanks guys - yep - print_r($myArray,true) spits the array structure to my txt file.

Comment: @mario You should put this into an answer as your solution has solved Shaun's problem. Nice work

Comment: `fyi - I have dataType:"json"` are you aware `dataType` refers to the response data, not the data you send.

Comment: No MrCode - I wasn't aware of that, but that's VERY handy to know - thanks for the heads up mate.